# How to convert a singlethreaded app to multithreaded

Tags: c#, multithreading

The central process for an app (in C#) I have written involves potentially many reads from a disk file and then processing those reads. The data is then written out via the `BinaryWriter` to the same output file.

The process is often very lengthy so I thought, if it is running on a multicore machine, it could instantiate a thread for each read up to cores x processors threads. each one would process the data and then write it out. There are no critical sections except the `BinaryWriter`.

I've noticed that when I the app on my machine with 4 cores taskmgr says it is using 25% of the CPU so I am guessing it is using 100% of one of the cores and the app could perhaps greatly benefit from using the other 3 cores as well.

If I use a class `Working` and a function `Working.work()` to do the processing and I have four cores to work with (and of course that 4 would not be hard coded; I'd interrogate to see how many I have and use that number what would I do?

Currently I have something like:

```
    Working working = new Working();

    while (bytesRead = binaryReader(ref buffer,0,bytesToRead) != 0)
    {
      work.buffer = buffer;
       working.work();
       binaryWriter(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
    }
```

It seems it would help to move this all to a thread. But I have to know when the threads are finished so the new read can be on a thread.

Comment: "I'm guessing" is bad for performance question - measure (or at very least estimate) first. I.e. very rough estimate in your case would be to run 4 instance of the same program at the same time and see if you get near 100% CPU load. I.e. you program may be disk bound and just happen to use one CPU completely...

Comment: You *never* want to read data from a disk with multiple threads.  You still have only one disk and it doesn't like being sent back-and-forth to handle reads from multiple threads.  Use a single thread for reading and a ConcurrentQueue to deliver the data to threads that process the data.  Don't worry about writing unless it is more than a gigabyte.

Comment: The reads do not occur in "natural" order. They are from different parts of the file. There are not a lot of reads one right after the other. The processing takes time, usually several seconds to many seconds.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good examples of asynchronous file IO and using tasks on MSN here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155757.aspx

In general, what you can do is make an asynchronous worker Queue (note: since .NET 4.0 there's a ConcurrentQueue collection that really helps facilitate asynchronous processing) of work items that you set an x-amount of tasks working at. Finished tasks you would then move to a non-asynchronous writer queue that you setup a different task for that awaits for new items to arrive.

See also more from Microsoft on this topic here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873173.aspx

Especially from the Producer / Consumer pattern downwards should be relevant to you.(though I don't see it using ConcurrentQueue, perhaps because that was written before 4.0?)